# get class name inside generic view class

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get class name of Generic view like below

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
   print self.__class__.__name__
```

But self is referring to app name rather `TestView`. My expected result is TestView.

Edit:

In the above code `self` does not work. Please refer comments. My requirement is to access `TestView` name.

Comment: That's not your code, because that wouldn't work at all (self is not defined at that point). Please show your actual code and output.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry for the noise, I was referring other line's log above the class as output. I figured out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code you provided does not work at all ... so I am making some assumptions here

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       TemplateView.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       print "I am",self.__class__.__name__
       print "My File:",self.template_name


class Whatever(TestView):
   pass


print Whatever()
print TestView()
```

Comment: But I am using the code like `class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/index.html'` and `views.TestView_asview()`.  Could you please let me know how can I accommodate this requirement with your code. Actually I am trying to refer html file based on the `TestView`. For example `TestView.html`

Comment: maybe my edits will fix your issue ... i dont understand what your comment has to do at all with `self.__class__.__name__`